# Difficulty with Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c#, dijkstra, vertex

I am new to advanced algorithms, so please bear with me. I am currently trying to get Dijkstra's algorithm to work, and have spend 2 days trying to figure this out. I also read the pseudo-code on Wikipedia and got this far.  I want to get the shortest distance between two vertices. In the below sample, I keep getting the wrong distance. Please help?

Sample graph setup is as follow:

```
Graph graph = new Graph();
graph.Vertices.Add(new Vertex("A"));
graph.Vertices.Add(new Vertex("B"));
graph.Vertices.Add(new Vertex("C"));
graph.Vertices.Add(new Vertex("D"));
graph.Vertices.Add(new Vertex("E"));

graph.Edges.Add(new Edge
                    {
                        From = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("A"),
                        To = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("B"),
                        Weight = 5
                    });

graph.Edges.Add(new Edge
                    {
                        From = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("B"),
                        To = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("C"),
                        Weight = 4
                    });

graph.Edges.Add(new Edge
                    {
                        From = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("C"),
                        To = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("D"),
                        Weight = 8
                    });


graph.Edges.Add(new Edge
                    {
                        From = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("D"),
                        To = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName("C"),
                        Weight = 8
                    });

//graph is passed as param with source and dest vertices
public int Run(Graph graph, Vertex source, Vertex destvertex)
{
    Vertex current = source;
    List<Vertex> queue = new List<Vertex>();

    foreach (var vertex in graph.Vertices)
    {
        vertex.Weight = int.MaxValue;
        vertex.PreviousVertex = null;
        vertex.State = VertexStates.UnVisited;
        queue.Add(vertex);
    }

    current = graph.Vertices.FindVertexByName(current.Name);
    current.Weight = 0;
    queue.Add(current);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        Vertex minDistance = queue.OrderBy(o => o.Weight).FirstOrDefault();
        queue.Remove(minDistance);

        if (current.Weight == int.MaxValue)
        {
            break;
        }

        minDistance.Neighbors = graph.GetVerTextNeigbours(current);

        foreach (Vertex neighbour in minDistance.Neighbors)
        {
            Edge edge = graph.Edges.FindEdgeByStartingAndEndVertex(minDistance, neighbour);
            int dist = minDistance.Weight + (edge.Weight);
            if (dist < neighbour.Weight)
            {
                //from this point onwards i get stuck
                neighbour.Weight = dist;
                neighbour.PreviousVertex = minDistance;
                queue.Remove(neighbour);
                queueVisited.Enqueue(neighbor);
            }
        }
        minDistance.State = VertexStates.Visited;
    }

      //here i want to record all node that was visited
     while (queueVisited.Count > 0)
    {
        Vertex temp = queueVisited.Dequeue();
        count += temp.Neighbors.Sum(x => x.Weight);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Tangential: consider a priority queue (or binary heap).

Comment: minDistance is the vertex with the minimum weight. Line 12 on the pseudo-code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are several immediate issues with the above code.

1. The `current` variable is never re-assigned, nor is the object mutatd, so `graph.GetVerTextNeigbours(current)` always returning the same set.

   As a result, this will never even find the target vertex if more than one edge must be traversed.
2. The neighbor node is removed from the queue via `queue.Remove(neighbour)`. *This is incorrect* and can prevent a node/vertex from being [re]explored. Instead, it should just have the weight updated in the queue.

   In this case the "decrease-key v in Q" is the psuedo-code results in a NO-OP in the implementation due object-mutation and not using a *priority queue* (i.e. sorted) structure.
3. The visited queue, as per `queueVisited.Enqueue(neighbor)` and the later "sum of all neighbor weights of all visited nodes", is incorrect.

   After the algorithm runs, the cost (`Weight`) of any node/vertex that was explored *is* the cost of the shortest path to that vertex. Thus, you can trivially ask the goal vertex what the cost is.

---

In addition, for the sake of the algorithm simplicity, I recommend giving up the "Graph/Vertex/Edge" layout initially created and, instead, pass in a simple Node. This Node can *enumerate* its neighbor Nodes, knows the weights to each neighbor, its own current weight, and the best-cost node to it.

Simply build this Node graph once, at the start, then pass the starting Node. This eliminates (or greatly simplifies) calls like `GetVerTextNeighbors` and `FindEdgeByStartingAndEndVertex`, and strange/unnecessary side-effects like assigning `Neighbors` each time the algorithm visits the vertex.